# Doctrine result set is empty array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, twig

I am trying to output data from a mySQL result set, and having an extremely difficult time doing so. When I pass the result set back to twig and use `{{ dump() }}` it returns an empty array when it shouldn't. When I run the same exact query from phpmyadmin, it populates results as expected, so it is not the query.

Any ideas why this is or what I am doing wrong here?

I appreciate any advice, many thanks in advance!

Controller

```
use Foo\FooBundle\Entity\Company;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

Controller

```
$stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM company");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

return $this->render('FooBundle:Default:search.html.twig', array('results' => $results);
```

Twig

```
{{ dump(results)  }}
```

Output

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump($results) within your controller (before the return)?

Comment: I get the following: `array(0) { } `

Comment: double check that you are using the right connection and not another database with 0 rows in company table

Comment: Then, it may be a doctrine connection/query issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Symfony / Doctrine, what do you mean by "make sure you are using the right connection"? I haven't created any connections anywhere else in the controller...

Comment: Then, take a look at [How to use Doctrine's DBAL Layer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html) section of the Cookbook.

Comment: @Ahmed, thank you. However, when I try to follow the example in the cookbook I get the following `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() `

Comment: This is what I tried: `$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
  $results = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM company');`

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting out with Symfony you should probably use some of the out of the box methods until you get a better picture.

Try something like the below to get all the companies instead.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$companies = $em->getRepository('FooFooBundle:Company')->findAll();
return $this->render('FooBundle:Default:search.html.twig', compact('companies'));
```